# Why is git remote named 'origin' by majority?

Tags: git

I always rename my remote as **github** or **bitbucket** . I'm curious why many people name their remote as **origin** most of the time, IMHO the name **origin** fits when cloning a repo, but seems not when adding it to your existing repo. Or am I just missing something

Comment: When adding a remote to existing repo, you have to choose a name, don't you? No default there, last time I checked. So use a name you think is best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the only way a remote "automatically" enters git is through a `git clone`, and here, "origin" is perfectly suitable. This probably also is the usual, 99% of the time way how remotes are created.

So people are used to "origin"; it will often be the term used in documentation/tutorials etc. . Hence, people tend to view "origin" as the default name of remote, or even as a *special* remote (which it is not, obviously).

The same goes for "master" - I'm sure many think "master" is a special branch when it absolutely is not; except from getting some special treatment during `git clone` and `git init`, it is a totally normal branch which can be deleted etc.

Comment: edited, i really want to say is by 'majority' not 'default'